# Eeschema, least painful way of changing pin order per symbol instance

Tags: schematics, kicad

I'm considering using Eeschema to create block diagrams. More or less just lots of abstract rectangles with ins and outs, interconnected. It will look like [xcos](https://www.scilab.org/software/xcos/model-building-edition)/Simulink.

For better readability, I'd like to be able to disentangle the wiring by adjusting symbol's order of pins ad hoc. Strictly speaking, symbol instance's order of pins.

Example: swapping spontaneously VDD and GP3 of U6 on the snippet below, and maybe pushing GP5 up and GP4 down, but only of U6 and not all PIC_8_PINS; connected wires should remain connected (I'll have to move them around for a better appearance, of course).

**Question**: Cloning a symbol for every variant of appearance sounds like a hassle. Does anybody know a better way?

I'm currently using MS Visio where I can freely move pins around, but I want "something electrical" with nets and buses and smart highlighting instead of, well, just lines. This is a specific question about eeschema, though, thus here and not on softwarerecs.

[image: example schematics]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In KiCad version 5, cloning each symbol that you want to modify is the only way to go.  Otherwise, changing a library symbol will change all instances of that symbol on your schematic.

This is changed in KiCad version 6 (not released yet, currently nightly beta builds are available as v5.99).  You can modify each instance of your symbol independently.  You might want to try out KiCad version 6 to see if it works for your needs.

Comment: A step by step guide: https://forum.kicad.info/t/modifying-each-instance-of-a-symbol-independently/28120/2